# Proving a sequence with a unique condition is eventually periodic.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, binary

Here’s the problem that I’m working on:

Let there be an infinite sequence of positive integers $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$. For each $a_i,$ multiply $a_i$ in base 10 by $5^{100}$, replace each digit with its remainder when divided by 2, and read the new number in binary. Call this number $a_{i+1}.$ If $a_1$ is any positive integer, show that for all large enough k, $a_k=a_{k+2^{100}}.$

By considering the number of digits, I realized that if $a_i$ is larger than $2^{101}$, the sequence eventually decreases until a term is less than $2^{101},$ so we just have to consider when $a_1$ is less than $2^{101}$. Further, I noticed that there’s a bijection between the numbers less than $2^{100}$ and the numbers between $2^{100}$ and $2^{101},$ so that might help. I also tried some sort of induction argument, but that got nowhere. I experimented with values smaller than 100, like $5^2, 5^3,$ etc and found that they all satisfy the problem conditions. However, I couldn’t find a pattern or anything useful, so I’m stuck here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not offering a solution here but instead of setting $a_1$ less than $2^{101}$ set $a_k$ to be that. Now, if you show that once it goes below $2^{100}$ it can never go back up you are done. Just pick the first $2^{100}+1$ numbers and pidgeonhole principle forces a repetition. The fact that the process is deterministic offers a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I originally thought of using pigeonhole principle as well. However the problem wants the period to be a divisor of $2^{100}$, while pigeonhole allows the period to be any integer less than $2^{100}$.

Comment: I was under the impression that periodicity was the hard part. Assuming you have that you can say that times 5 retains the mod2, times25 the mod4 etc and you get your result.

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure what you mean when you say that times 5 retains the mod 2 and times 25 retains the mod 4.

Comment: Assume that instead of $5^{100}$ you multiply with just 5 and you start with an odd number you will always get odd numbers. Same with even. So a periodicity of $2^{99}+1$ for example is not possible because there are not enough even(respectively odd) numbers in the set. So my thinking is that once you prove periodicity you can prune some values by looking at the moduli. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it can remove some values but not enough. If I understand you correctly, multiplying by $5^{100}$ only keeps up to mod 16.

Comment: For instance, nothing’s stopping the period from being 3, 5, $2^{35}+5.$